# Up button is not working with my custom transition

Tags: java, android

I defined customWindowAnimation in values>styles. This work properly with back button but when I press the UP button in toolbar the transition is not working :(

Could you please help me to find a solution? . thanks in advance .

Here's the resource file

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#c9416f</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#c4265b</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#c21b53</item>

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

manifest file `

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".eshohor"
        android:parentActivityName="com.sonalirod.run6.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.parentActivity"
        android:value=".MainActivity"
        />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".namkoron" />

    <activity android:name=".Jelaporicity"/>

    <activity android:name=".potovumi"
              android:parentActivityName="com.sonalirod.run6.MainActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".thanasomoho"></activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: If you post the code you have written (the relevant parts) it will help a people answer your question!

Comment: plz post your code. Also post manifest file.

Comment: it's edited with details :)

Comment: i found solution by mayself 
just catch the transition via that two line 


`  if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
            return true;
        }`